# After making some changes to my .aspx.cs file of my project hosted at smarterasp.net, I can't see the changes in live

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx-user-control

I am new to C# and ASP.NET and I need help. After making changes to my .aspx.cs file, I am unable to see the changes. Do I need to rebuild or delete cache? If yes, how can I do this when the project is live?

I modified a .aspx.cs file and deployed it via FileManager of my hosting provider, SmarterASP.NET, but I can't see the effect of my changes. It appears that I need to rebuild the project, but I can't find any section in the hosting control that can help me rebuild the project. What's the best approach to make this change propagate in production? The old file is still being considered, which probably means that the changes can't propagate during runtime.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to rebuild the project and upload the `MyProject.dll` to the bin folder of the server.

Comment: You may refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-build-simple-asp-net-core-website/, just follow the steps and I can make sure that you can publish your .net core without any issue.